# Health travel insurance for pregnant woman (34th week) and unborn baby

Tags: usa, canada, insurance, female-travellers, pregnancy

A Canadian woman is going on a trip to the USA, and the flight back to Canada is on the 1st day of her 34th week of her pregnancy. The pregnancy has been completely normal so far. Is there any travel insurance company that will sell a plan that will cover:

1. Any emergency medical complications of the **mother** relating to the pregnancy that might arise during the trip?
2. Medical care for the **child**, should the child be born prematurely?

In my own research, I could not yet find such a plan, with either Canadian or US insurance companies. For #1, I can find coverage up to 32nd week of pregnancy, but nothing that goes as far as the 34th.

I'd be ok with purchasing 2 separate plans for the 2 points above, so I'd appreciate answers even if they only address #1 or #2 above.

Comment: This [UK insurer](https://www.allcleartravel.co.uk/kb/cover-provided-pregnancy/) covers up to 36 weeks, and to travel to the US, although I can't figure out whether it would sell to someone outside the UK.

Comment: You should check that the airline will board a woman that pregnant.

Answer (score 3):

You need to talk to a real life insurance broker. They will find you a company who is willing to underwrite this, you can insure anything imaginable and beyond. Expect a hefty fee. I wouldn't be surprised at thousands of dollars. More than 10% of babies are premature, you are looking at ~8-10K USD for the birth and who knows what if the infant heaven forbid needs an NICU -- that might run to 10K per *day*.

And mind Karlson's comment, United won't let you fly past 8th months (=32 weeks) and if you have bought a ticket from Air Canada (where the cut off is 36 weeks) it might be a code share on United. Be careful.

Comment: life insurance? to cover for dying in childbirth?

Comment: 8 months is a little more than 34 weeks, not 32.  Still cutting it close though.

Comment: @NateEldredge you are right, sorry, I thought every months is 4 wks which it obviously is not.